# $\frac{n}{2} < 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{2^n-1}<n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to show that for $n\geqslant 2$
$$\frac{n}{2} < 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{2^n-1}<n$$

Comment: It's not true for $n=0,1$, you might want to specify for what $n$

Comment: fair enough. I just wish comments no longer applying would be deleted.

Comment: So, the sum in the center is to be interpreted
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le 2^{n}-1}\frac{1}{k},
$$
where $n\ge 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the sum as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}{\frac{1}{k}}> 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}+ \frac{1}{8}+ \frac{1}{8}\right)...$$
So that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}{\frac{1}{k}} > 1 + \frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2^n}>\frac{n}{2}$$
If instead you group them by the lower power of two you easily get the other limit.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac12<2^n\left(\frac1{2^{n+1}-1}\right)<\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}\frac1k<2^n\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)=1$$